# WSO2 IS 5.10 SAML2 Toolkit Missing

Tags: wso2

I am running WSO2 IS 5.10 on [Linux 4.4.0-176-generic x86_64] and am logged in using the built in admin account.  I need to troubleshoot a SAML Request generated from the testing of an IdP and SP that I have setup.  I would like to use the SAML2 Toolkit from the Tools tab, but that functionality is missing.  I remember this functionality being available in my 5.09 setup.  Has this functionality been removed with 5.10 or is there a configuration that needs to be updated to make this available?

[Image of carbon UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKz5F.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a SAML enabled service provider first in that version in order to use the tool.